# Do we use article with adjectives modifying uncountable nouns?

Tags: articles

In our daily unexamined routines of language, we easily overlook linguistic gaps.

In our daily unexamined routines of language, we easily overlook the linguistic gaps.

Comment: As a native speaker, I must point out that *I don't understand* the cited text, so it's not easy to say whether the article would affect the "meaning" (whatever it is).

Comment: The article is not required. Think of "linguistic gaps" as having a kind of generic meaning.

Comment: @BillJ: As I said, I don't understand the cited text anyway. Specifically, I don't know (or care, for the purposes of my argument here) what "linguistic gaps" refers to. But *syntactically*, it seems to me that including the article strongly implies that such gaps *do in fact exist*. Whereas *without* the article that implication is far weaker, which allows the cited example to be "valid" even if the writer and/or his audience are open-minded (or even sceptical) as to whether they exist or not. So although it's "not required", it *could* have semantic significance.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence can work in both versions. But the first one is the best in your sentence current structure as you are talking about those gaps **in general**. Whereas in the second version, I would expect as a reader "**the** linguistic gaps" to be defined either previously or in the current position of their mention since they have become **specified** by the addition of the definite article.

A clarification example *(which means that the following extra text isn't necessarily the one to add. This solely depends on what you want to convey)*:

> In our daily unexamined routines of language, we easily overlook the linguistic gaps that are about *syntax, grammar, and phonetics concepts.*

Or even better

> In our daily unexamined routines of language, we easily overlook the linguistic *syntax, grammar, and phonetics* gaps.

---

Here's an [article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles-with-plural-nouns/) about this matter.

Comment: I don't think including the article has any implications for whether or not the noun might be further modified. All it does is unambiguously indicate that there definitely ***are*** some "linguistic gaps" (where without the article it might be equivalent to *...overlook **any** linguistic gaps*, which allows for the possibility that no such gaps might exist).

Comment: Yes, and that's why **any** "linguistic gaps" is about indicating them **in general**, whereas **some** "linguistic gaps" is about a particular, specified group of such gaps. I don't see where my answer and your comment contradict each other. But I totally respect your point of view alongside the downvote.

Comment: I think you miss my point. With no additional context, there's no reason to assume that including the article refers to any *specific* (previously, or contextually identified) "gaps". The *only* "semantic" content ***the*** carries is that ***at least some gaps do in fact exist***. Whereas with ***any*** it's explicitly acknowledged that there might *not* be any gaps, and with no "determiner" at all there's no implication one way or the other on that specific point.

Comment: Without the article, there may or may not be "linguistic gaps"; thus, this statement is stated _in general_. It doesn't provide any further information to assume anything about it. While with the definite-article, it makes the existence of those gaps certain. Now, whether it determines specific gaps or not (which is a possibility, not an actuality) it would depend on what the OP's want to convey.

Comment: Therefore, I wrote in my answer that it can be stated in that structure and be totally correct, but what makes the version without the article better is that this one when being heard, it **would be expected** to have additional information that justifies the presence of its definite article.

Comment: All I can do is repeat my earlier assertion that I see no justification for your point about *...would be expected to have additional information*. As regards introducing the concept "in general" here to mean *regardless of whether or not any such gaps do in fact exist*, I'm not convinced that's a useful way of looking at things in this specific context.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _ I have clarified my point further in my answer. As for the second disapproval, I have asked about this and a native stated: "I'd say the null article is mostly about generality — an unwillingness to refer to definite gaps, and an unwillingness to definitely state that such gaps even exist. “Any” is about the fact we don’t know if such gaps really exist or not in a given context." It appears according to his statement that what "any" indicates is the same as (the generality of the sentence) do.